# Embedded Jetty SSL configuration. https only access

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to start an embedded Jetty and make it SSL enabled, only. So that users will only be able to access it on port 8443.

the code looks like below:

```
    HttpConfiguration http_config = new HttpConfiguration();
    http_config.setSecureScheme( "https" );
    http_config.setSecurePort( 8443 );
    http_config.setOutputBufferSize( 32768 );

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory
            .setKeyStorePath( "./path_to_keystore/keystore.p12" );
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword( "pass" );
    sslContextFactory
            .setTrustStorePath( "./path_to_truststore/trustore.jks" );
    sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword( "changeit" );

    HttpConfiguration https_config = new HttpConfiguration( http_config );
    https_config.addCustomizer( new SecureRequestCustomizer() );

    ServerConnector https = new ServerConnector( m_jettyServer, new SslConnectionFactory( sslContextFactory,
            "http/1.1" ), new HttpConnectionFactory( https_config ) );
    https.setPort( 8443 );
    https.setIdleTimeout( 500000 );

    m_jettyServer.setConnectors( new Connector[] {  https } );
    m_jettyServer.setHandler(createHandlerFromWebAppContext());
```

The Jetty server handler is the application's web.xml.

After i am doing the above i try to access the web-app at

```
https://www.my_web_app_localhost:8443
```

but no web page at this port.

Then i am accessing

```
http://www.my_web_app_localhost:8888
```

and for some reason the webpage can be accessed.

I m really confused, as i explicitly set the port. I cannot really understand why the app can be accessed at 8888.

Can someone please help me understand the above?

Comment: can you include how you created `m_jettyServer` in your code snippet?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thanks for your comment. I found the error and it was indeed in the way the Server was created. Now i am getting invalid keystore format exception for the .p12 certificate. Do you know if i can only use .jks format ?